# r- bind rows of a list of dataframes, while keeping empty dataframes as NA rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, rbind

I'm looking for a way to rbind a list of dataframes (around 7000 dataframes of one row or empty) into a single dataframe but without removing the empty dataframes of the list.

```
## Example of data
l <- list(Name1 = data.frame(), 
                 Name2 = data.frame(V1 = "A", V2 = "B", stringsAsFactors = F), 
                 Name3 = data.frame(V1="B", V2= NA, V3 ="C", stringsAsFactors = F))

> l
$Name1
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

$Name2
  V1 V2
1  A  B

$Name3
  V1 V2 V3
1  B NA  C
```

So i've tried some dplyr solution but it doesn't keep the empty dataframe (not suprising cause it has no row)

```
## rbind
library(dplyr)

df <- bind_rows(l,.id = "NAME")

> df
   NAME V1   V2   V3
1 Name2  A    B <NA>
2 Name3  B <NA>    C
```

Is there a simple way to get something like this ?

```
> df
   NAME V1   V2   V3
1 Name1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 Name2  A    B <NA>
3 Name3  B <NA>    C
```

It appears that using tidyr::complete works on my example,

```
df <- bind_rows(l,.id = "NAME") %>% complete(NAME = names(l))
```

but not for my whole dataset.
Here the head of my actual dataset

```
dput(head(GNPlaceName))
list(Seydikemer = structure(list(), class = "data.frame", row.names = integer(0)), 
    Fanna = structure(list(timezone.gmtOffset = "1", timezone.timeZoneId = "Europe/Rome", 
        timezone.dstOffset = "2", bbox.east = "12.7623022680034", 
        bbox.south = "46.1770686700141", bbox.north = "46.1904973822354", 
        bbox.west = "12.7415900814293", bbox.accuracyLevel = "10", 
        asciiName = "Fanna", astergdem = "258", countryId = "3175395", 
        fcl = "P", srtm3 = "263", score = "62.2252464294434", 
        adminId2 = "3170146", adminId3 = "6537931", countryCode = "IT", 
        adminCodes2.ISO3166_2 = "PN", adminCodes1.ISO3166_2 = "36", 
        adminId1 = "3176525", lat = "46.18455", fcode = "PPLA3", 
        continentCode = "EU", elevation = "274", adminCode2 = "PN", 
        adminCode3 = "093020", adminCode1 = "06", lng = "12.75161", 
        geonameId = "3177221", toponymName = "Fanna", population = "1500", 
        adminName5 = "", adminName4 = "", adminName3 = "Fanna", 
        alternateNames.name = "Fane", alternateNames.lang = "fur", 
        adminName2 = "Province of Pordenone", name = "Fanna", 
        fclName = "city, village,...", countryName = "Italy", 
        fcodeName = "seat of a third-order administrative division", 
        adminName1 = "Friuli Venezia Giulia"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), Warsaw = structure(list(timezone.gmtOffset = "1", 
        timezone.timeZoneId = "Europe/Warsaw", timezone.dstOffset = "2", 
        bbox.east = "21.2711512942955", bbox.south = "52.0978496125492", 
        bbox.north = "52.368153944595", bbox.west = "20.8516883368428", 
        bbox.accuracyLevel = "10", asciiName = "Warsaw", astergdem = "121", 
        countryId = "798544", fcl = "P", srtm3 = "113", score = "145.618896484375", 
        adminId2 = "6695624", adminId3 = "7531926", countryCode = "PL", 
        adminCodes1.ISO3166_2 = "14", adminId1 = "858787", lat = "52.22977", 
        fcode = "PPLC", continentCode = "EU", adminCode2 = "1465", 
        adminCode3 = "146501", adminCode1 = "78", lng = "21.01178", 
        geonameId = "756135", toponymName = "Warsaw", population = "1702139", 
        adminName5 = "", adminName4 = "", adminName3 = "Warsaw", 
        alternateNames.name = "Warskou", alternateNames.lang = "af", 
        alternateNames.isShortName = "TRUE", alternateNames.isPreferredName = "TRUE", 
        adminName2 = "Warszawa", name = "Warsaw", fclName = "city, village,...", 
        countryName = "Poland", fcodeName = "capital of a political entity", 
        adminName1 = "Mazovia"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    `Gaverina Terme` = structure(list(timezone.gmtOffset = "1", 
        timezone.timeZoneId = "Europe/Rome", timezone.dstOffset = "2", 
        bbox.east = "9.89570095710424", bbox.south = "45.7540309868418", 
        bbox.north = "45.7576290305937", bbox.west = "9.8836191498607", 
        bbox.accuracyLevel = "10", asciiName = "Gaverina Terme", 
        astergdem = "502", countryId = "3175395", fcl = "P", 
        srtm3 = "494", score = "22.0922546386719", adminId2 = "3182163", 
        adminId3 = "6542955", countryCode = "IT", adminCodes2.ISO3166_2 = "BG", 
        adminCodes1.ISO3166_2 = "25", adminId1 = "3174618", lat = "45.75578", 
        fcode = "PPLA3", continentCode = "EU", elevation = "509", 
        adminCode2 = "BG", adminCode3 = "016110", adminCode1 = "09", 
        lng = "9.88666", geonameId = "6534969", toponymName = "Gaverina Terme", 
        population = "358", adminName5 = "", adminName4 = "", 
        adminName3 = "Gaverina Terme", alternateNames.name = "ITGVR", 
        alternateNames.lang = "unlc", adminName2 = "Provincia di Bergamo", 
        name = "Gaverina Terme", fclName = "city, village,...", 
        countryName = "Italy", fcodeName = "seat of a third-order administrative division", 
        adminName1 = "Lombardy"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    `Cañaveral de León` = structure(list(timezone.gmtOffset = "1", 
        timezone.timeZoneId = "Europe/Madrid", timezone.dstOffset = "2", 
        bbox.east = "-6.49382969510649", bbox.south = "37.9986794024971", 
        bbox.north = "38.0346539975029", bbox.west = "-6.53950370489351", 
        bbox.accuracyLevel = "1", asciiName = "Canaveral de Leon", 
        astergdem = "524", countryId = "2510769", fcl = "P", 
        srtm3 = "528", score = "45.6841278076172", adminId2 = "2516547", 
        adminId3 = "6358196", countryCode = "ES", adminCodes2.ISO3166_2 = "H", 
        adminCodes1.ISO3166_2 = "AN", adminId1 = "2593109", lat = "38.01667", 
        fcode = "PPLA3", continentCode = "EU", adminCode2 = "H", 
        adminCode3 = "21020", adminCode1 = "51", lng = "-6.51667", 
        geonameId = "2520292", toponymName = "Cañaveral de León", 
        population = "0", adminName5 = "", adminName4 = "", adminName3 = "Cañaveral de León", 
        alternateNames.name = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ca%C3%B1averal_de_Le%C3%B3n", 
        alternateNames.lang = "link", adminName2 = "Huelva", 
        name = "Cañaveral de León", fclName = "city, village,...", 
        countryName = "Spain", fcodeName = "seat of a third-order administrative division", 
        adminName1 = "Andalusia"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    Voranava = structure(list(timezone.gmtOffset = "3", timezone.timeZoneId = "Europe/Minsk", 
        timezone.dstOffset = "3", bbox.east = "25.3283727016391", 
        bbox.south = "54.139144795013", bbox.north = "54.159255204987", 
        bbox.west = "25.2940272983609", bbox.accuracyLevel = "2", 
        asciiName = "Voranava", astergdem = "170", countryId = "630336", 
        fcl = "P", srtm3 = "172", score = "62.4154739379883", 
        countryCode = "BY", adminCodes1.ISO3166_2 = "HR", adminId1 = "628035", 
        lat = "54.1492", fcode = "PPLA2", continentCode = "EU", 
        adminCode1 = "03", lng = "25.3112", geonameId = "619979", 
        toponymName = "Voranava", population = "6500", adminName5 = "", 
        adminName4 = "", adminName3 = "", alternateNames.name = "Воранава", 
        alternateNames.lang = "be", adminName2 = "", name = "Voranava", 
        fclName = "city, village,...", countryName = "Belarus", 
        fcodeName = "seat of a second-order administrative division", 
        adminName1 = "Grodnenskaya"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
bind_rows(l, .id = "Names") %>%
 complete(Names = names(l))

  Names V1    V2    V3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Name1 <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
2 Name2 A     B     <NA> 
3 Name3 B     <NA>  C
```

Comment: Thanks, that works on my example, but for some reason, when I do the same on my data (7000 dataframes of 1 row or empty, with around 40 variables), I get a dataframe with all names but with NAs everywhere else...

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data using `dput()`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've just edit my message, but the strange things is your solution actually works on the sample of the data, but still not on the whole dataset. In any case, thank you for your awnser.

Comment: That's quite strange. Is there any warning or error message?

Comment: I've just found the problem : one of my df has no name, once this error corrected, your solution works ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate a column in your empty dataFrame first, try this

```
l <- list(Name1 = data.frame(V1=NA), 
             Name2 = data.frame(V1 = "A", V2 = "B", stringsAsFactors = F), 
             Name3 = data.frame(V1="B", V2= NA, V3 ="C", stringsAsFactors = F))

df <- bind_rows(l,.id = "NAME")
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by @tmfmnk works well. Thank you again.

If this didn't work on all my data at first, it's because an item (a dataframe) on my list didn't have a name. Once this error has been corrected, it works perfectly.